# Javascript calling JSF handler method

Tags: javascript, handler

I am reading an xml file using javascript and then I need to submit my form so that it calls a particular method in my JSF handler. Usually this can be done on a jsp when user clicks a button by having an actionlistener like so:

```
<h:commandLink styleClass="button" action="#{myHandler.outcome}" actionListener="#{myHandler.doNext}">
    <span><h:outputText value="#{text.button_submit}" /></span> </h:commandLink>
```

I am not sure how to call a method like 'doNext' above in the handler from javascript. I cannot do a simple:

```
document.form.submit();
```

as it then repeats the processing i have already done. I want to read values from an xml file and then call a particular method in handler. Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: I resolved this issue by placing a hidden button on the form and then in my javascript I simply called button.click() which executed the actionListener associated with that button. So I basically just imitated the button click in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to this. I added a hidden button to my jsp like:

```
<p id="hiddenButton" style="display:none;" >
           <h:commandLink id="hiddenRegButton" styleClass="button" action="#{myHandler.doNext}" />
        </p>
```

and in my javascript I used jQuery to execute the click which leads t the "doNext" method in my Handler to get executed.

```
jQuery('#hiddenRegButton').click();
```

this was easier than I thought.